# $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, (x,y) \ne0 \\0, (x,y) = 0 \end{cases}$ Determine if the function is continuous at the origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, (x,y) \ne0 \\0, (x,y) = 0 \end{cases}$$ Determine if the function is continuous at the origin.

Now when $(x,y) \ne 0$, letting $x = y^2$ I have that $\frac{y^4}{y^4+y^4} = \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly when $y=x$ I get $\frac{x^3}{x^2+x^4} = \frac{x}{1+x^2} \to 0$, hence the function is not continuous at the origin. Now I tried using epsilon-delta for this, but couldn't get it to work. What's would be wrong with my approach?

We have that $|f(x)-f(0)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $\|x-0\| = \|x\| = |x| < \delta$.

So let $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta= \frac{\varepsilon}{y^2}$ $$|f(x)-f(0)| = |f(x)| = \frac{|x|y^2}{|x^2+y^4|} \leqslant |x|y^2 < \delta y^2 =\varepsilon.$$

But this is not true since just above we showed that the function is not continuous at the origin. I guess the problem is $\frac{|x|y^2}{|x^2+y^4|} \leqslant |x|y^2$ which isn't probably true?

Comment: The inequality $\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq |x|y^2$ does not hold.

Comment: The path-dependence proof suffices, but you have some notational issues where sometimes $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and sometimes $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's not true, because you're saying $\frac{1} {\vert x^2 +y^4\vert} \le 1 $ and that's not true when you consider "small" x and y.

Comment: How did you find the inequality? The usual bound is: $\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{|x|}{y^2}$, because $y^4\leq x^2 + y^4$, which is not sufficient to assure the existence of the limit.

Comment: @LuisGiraldoGonzalez I didn't consider "small" $x$ and $y$ as Adriano stated.

Comment: Try to approach towards the origin via the curves $x = my^2$ for different values of $m.$

Comment: But, it is mandatory to consider small values of $x$ and $y$, because you are approaching $(0,0)$. That is the idea behind the concept of limit.

Comment: @LuisGiraldoGonzalez It seems that even with the bound $\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{|x|}{y^2}$ I can still find an $\delta$ for the epsilon proof?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Recall what $\delta$ means, this is, all the points $(x,y)$ at a distance less than $\delta$ from the origin. The upper bound in my previous comments does not work because, if you fix $x$, no matter how small, you can take smaller values of $y$ and the ratio $|x|/y^2$ blows to infinity. That fact is telling you nothing about the behavior of the function near the origin.

Comment: But from the definition, I have that $x < \delta$, wouldn't that let me choose $\delta = \varepsilon y^2$ and I would have that $\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{|x|}{y^2} < \frac{\delta}{y^2} = \frac{\varepsilon y^2}{y^2} = \varepsilon$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The statement "$f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$" has the definition: "for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, if $(x,y)$ is within $\delta$ of $(0,0)$, then $f(x,y)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $f(0,0)$".

The first quantified variable is $\varepsilon$, which must be an arbitrary constant (not depending on any other variables).

The next quantified variable is $\delta$, which can be chosen in terms of $\varepsilon$ (since that variable has already been quantified), *but must be independent of $x$ and $y$* (since those variables have not been quantified yet when we get to $\delta$). This is the source of the error in the proof—you set $\delta= \varepsilon/y$ which is not allowed.

(And the next quantified variables are $x$ and $y$, which are allowed to be constrained by $\delta$ since that variable has already been quantified.)

Comment: I see thanks! In the single variable case $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$ so this goes on in the multivariable case, but $\delta$ cannot depend on any of the variables?

Comment: @RobPratt Are you saying that picking $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{y^2}$ is "legal" afterall?

Comment: Exactly!!! The selection of $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ and on the point $(x_0, y_0)$. If $\delta$ depends **only** on $\epsilon$ then you have _uniform_ continuity. This is a subtle but quite important difference.